# The current path, =/login/, didn’t match any of these. Django

Tags: django, django-views

```py
def loginPage(request):
    page = 'login'
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'user dose not exist')

    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
        

    context = {'page':page}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Here is the django code snippet of mine in the views.py file but it gives me an error saying,

The current path, =/login/, didn’t match any of these. Django

As i can see i have entered the correct path but it's not working

Here is my urls.py file

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),

    path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
    path('update-room/<str:pk>/', views.updateRoom, name="update-room"),
    path('delete-room/<str:pk>/', views.deleteRoom, name="delete-room"),

    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

I want to know the reason for the given error.

Comment: could you share more details including a screenshot of the error and HTML file showing how are you handling the click button to log in?

Comment: Share the href of the anchor tag that brings about this error.

Comment: Please share your form html code

Comment: Author should include more information like screenshot of the error, url configuration